# Restore using Windows Server Backup on a clean machine

Tags: windows-server-2008

I have a physical machine that I ran Sysprep on, Sysprep restores your system back into the disk image when you first run the computer... All data will be lost since the old disk image has been overwritten by the default disk image or factory default image.

Once I boot this physical machine with a fresh install of Windows Server 2008 R2, could I start Windows Server Backup, and restore from a backup .vhd saved on another server?

I can create the same Windows Account user name and password and use the same computer name.

I would be attempting to restore the C:/ drive using Windows Server Backup

Comment: Sysprep doesn't erase data, if it did what would be the point of using it? Additionally, if your plan is to restore a pre-sysprep backup to this server then why are you using sysprep in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As joeqwerty pointed out, Sysprep does not remove data per se. It will reset the Administrator user account, including data stored in the Administrator user’s folders, etc. however.

If this is what happened, the environment should be largely intact, including Windows Server Backup functionality, so yes, you will be able to restore from backup. You will not be able to restore the operating system drive however, as that cannot be done from within the active operating system environment. If you want to restore the environment from a backup, you will need to use the image recovery functionality from the Repair your computer option on the installation media or a system repair disk.